# Request.Cookie value not getting on next run from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.net project, while loading the login page, it will take the azure login details and save to response. So running the project next time we need to take it from request, but the value is always null.

```
   HttpCookie azureCookie = Request.Cookies["SendToV2azuread"];
   if (azureCookie == null)
   {
      azureCookie = new HttpCookie("SendToV2azuread");
   }
   cache = azureCookie.Value;
   //some code azure code
   azureCookie.Value = "new Value from azure code";
   azureCookie.Expires = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
   Response.Cookies.Add(azureCookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to azure value length, now I have split into 3 parts and added in 3 different cookie and it is working as expected.